# Is it true that every PDE is a system of first order quasi-linear PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

As shown in Folland (*Introduction to PDE*, page 48), a fully non-linear PDE of the form
$$
\partial_{x_n}^ku=G(x,(\partial^\beta u)_{|\beta |\leq k, \beta _n<k})
$$
($G$ smooth) is equivalent to a first order quasi-linear system, ie they have the same regular solutions.

Does this continue to hold without assuming that the term $\partial_{x_n}^ku$ can be isolated? I.e. can we always think of a general fully non-linear PDE
$$
F(x,(\partial^ \beta u)_{|\beta|\leq k})=0
$$
as a system of first order quasi-linear PDEs?

Comment: Might be related, the Legendre Transform can break up multiple PDEs of second order to twice as many PDEs ofcfirst order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For each multi-index $\beta$ such that $|\beta| < k$, let $p_\beta$ be a function. Then the PDE can be written as
\begin{align*}
F(x, (p_\beta)_{|\beta|<k}, (\partial_kp_{\alpha})_{1 \le k \le n, |\alpha|=k-1}) &= 0\\
\partial_kp_{\alpha} &= p_{k,\alpha},\ 1 \le k \le n, |\alpha| \le k-2
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answers but as far as I can tell this is not a quasi-linear system, since it is not linear in the derivatives that appear in $F$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. If I can find the time, I'll try to make another attempt. By the way, the process of doing this is known as prolongation. You might be able to find a reference for this.